# Multiple server builds with the same image - one will not run a specific crontab line

Tags: scripting, cron

We have a watchdog script that runs on a number of servers that will restart some services if they fail.  We have them running successfully on a number of sites, however we have one site which will not run the crontab entry that triggers the watchdog.  If we run the entry from the command line - it works fine

When the watchdog is installed it puts the following line into crontab.  You just remove the '#' to enable it

```
#*/5 * * * * root /usr/local/fusion/scripts/watch_fusion_services 60
```

Other entries in Crontab do run - it's just this one line

I have done the following to try and resolve the issue

- Removed crontab entries for the watchdog and reinstalled watchdog
- Checked syslog getting this error:

```
 Error: bad hour; while reading /etc/crontab
```

- Changed the crontab line to be 6 minutes instead of 5 (as there was another cron job running every 5 minutes as well at this site)
- Syslog error no longer occurring, however watchdog still does not work via crontab.  No error messages in syslog
- tested running the crontab line from the command prompt - this works okay
- Attempted same process on a test VM - worked okay
- Attempted same process in live environment - tested okay
- checked versions of the ICA - both the same - GNU/Linux 3.13.0-117-generic x86_64
- ran ntqp -p on server that is having issues - time is 'LOCAL'.
- typed entry by hand - same issues occurring

I could try rebooting the server - but it seems a bit extreme for one crontab entry not working

Does anyone have any ideas about this one?

Answer (score 0):

There was a line of junk in crontab that we all missed.  One of the other technicians I work with pointed it as he walked past our department.

Sometimes you just can't see the wood from the trees when you are looking at a problem too long